# Option accepted with and without value

Tags: python, argparse

I have a small script and I need it to be able to accept parameter with value and withou value.

```
./cha.py --pretty-xml
./cha.py --pretty-xml=5
```

I have this.

```
parser.add_argument('--pretty-xml', nargs='?', dest='xml_space', default=4)
```

But when I use --pretty-xml in xml_space will be 'none'. If I dont write this parameter in xml_space is stored the default value. I would need the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the `default` parameter and use a custom `Action` instead:

```
class PrettyXMLAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if not values:
            values = 4
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser.add_argument('--pretty-xml', nargs='?', type=int, dest='xml_space', action=PrettyXMLAction)
```

Demo:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--pretty-xml', nargs='?', type=int, dest='xml_space', action=PrettyXMLAction)
PrettyXMLAction(option_strings=['--pretty-xml'], dest='xml_space', nargs='?', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args('--pretty-xml'.split())
Namespace(xml_space=4)
>>> parser.parse_args('--pretty-xml=5'.split())
Namespace(xml_space=5)
>>> parser.parse_args(''.split())
Namespace(xml_space=None)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `const` keyword:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--pretty-xml", nargs="?", type=int, dest="xml_space", const=4)
print(parser.parse_args([]))
print(parser.parse_args(['--pretty-xml']))
print(parser.parse_args(['--pretty-xml=5']))
```

results in

```
Namespace(xml_space=None)
Namespace(xml_space=4)
Namespace(xml_space=5)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. From the docs:

"The `const` argument of `add_argument()` is used to hold constant values... When `add_argument()` is called with option strings (like `-f` or `--foo`) and `nargs='?'`... this creates an optional argument that can be followed by zero or one command-line arguments. When parsing the command line, if the option string is encountered with no command-line argument following it, the value of const will be assumed instead."