# python 2.7 check if argument has been passed from command prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

kind of stuck in a problem. I need to check if a certain parameter has been passed via command prompt while executing a python script.

I execute the python file as `python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger 1`

While on my python script I used `argparse` as

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-ip', '--ip')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

How can i check if the argument `trigger` has been passed or not. If there is trigger in the parameter then grab the value of trigger and print it.

And the script should be able to run with all of following commands

`python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1` without the trigger parameter.

`python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger` without the value of the trigger parameter.

`python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger 1` with all the parameters and its value.

Further more the execution command is auto generated from an automated system, and hence the parameters can be more, For example, The command can be  `python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger 1 prompt 0 base 5 .....` , and the `-trigger 1 prompt 0 base 5` etc are auto generated, therefore I want to implement the `parameter check` in my python script so that it can handle any number of the passed parameters.

Comment: Use `parser.add_argument('-trigger', '--trigger', action=store_true)` instead, and now you can use `if args.trigger: <do something`. See also the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#introducing-optional-arguments).

Comment: @Evert, that is an answer not a comment

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's the wrong answer though.

Comment: Use `store_const`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041107/python-argparse-strore-true-and-store-optional-option-in-one-argument/16041243#16041243 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024635/option-accepted-with-and-without-value. I think that is what you want.

Comment: To be clear: you want to know 1/ whether `-trigger` has been used, and 2/ what the value is when it has been used? What about the use of `-trigger` without a value (e.g. `python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger`)?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? The very purpose of `argparse` is to abstract away this stuff. So there appears to be a design flaw and the correct answer would be to use another approach.

Comment: @Evert : To be specific, I need need my script to run as either `python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1` or with `python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger 1` . I don't need the value of trigger.

Comment: and one more thing, I can run this script as `python run.py -ip 127.0.0.1 -trigger 1` and get the value of trigger, if it is 1 then run method A else run Method B, but the thing is, I want my class to be robost to handle more parameters for further implementations.

Comment: More parameters, or more values? And what if there is no value specified for `trigger`?

Comment: More parameters, There are many methods inside the class, which are independent to the arguments passed, but the methods are dependent to the class constructors, I have implemented multiple constructors which will be called depending on the parameters passed. And the python execution script from console is auto generated from a automated system, hence the parameters are not fixed. And to solve this I need to check which parameter are present when the script is called.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question: if you want more parameters, you just add them with `add_argument`? You may need to show more code or examples, since your problem definition at the moment appears unclear.

Comment: Well I have now updated the question slightly, and it should be clear now, Main thing is , the script should be able to run with or without trigger parameter, and if there is trigger parameter then print its value.

Comment: Answer is the same, and has been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16041243/707650) before: use `store_const`, and compare `args.trigger` to `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `--trigger` argument to your parser

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-ip', '--ip')
parser.add_argument('-t','--trigger', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If `--trigger` is absent, `args.trigger` should be the default (e.g. `None`)

If present without argument, `args.trigger` will be `[]`, empty list

Otherwise it will be a list of all the strings that follow.  Technically that's true for the [] case as well.

With `nargs='?'`, `const` can be defined, but then you can only give it one argument.

`nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` should also work.  If will grab everything after `--trigger`, whether it looks like a flag ('--') or not. That can be handy if you are passing the strings onto another program.  See the example in the docs

`parse_known_args` is also handy if you want to parse some strings now, and handle the rest later.  Again this is in the docs.

A positional argument with `nargs='*'` is also handy.  And `'--'` in the input strings is useful to separate strings that should be parsed from those that should be viewed simple argument strings.

Answer (score -1):

A minimal example of argparse, but you should read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check for trigger')
parser.add_argument('-trigger', help='trigger value')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.trigger is not None:
    print("trigger value: {}".format(args.trigger))
```

You get the outputs:

```
○ → ./trigger.py

○ → ./trigger.py -trigger=
trigger value: 

○ → ./trigger.py -trigger 1
trigger value: 1
```